# How do you add column search filter on JqGrid on sever-side code?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I'm passing Json data to the JqGrid table through my controller? I want paging and sorting to be done through my controller as well as filter/search.This is a dynamic search-filter so searchOnEnter = false. I don't want loadonce = true because it will stop paging/sorting, but it will enable client-side filter/search. I want my filter search to work like [this](http://mvcjqgrid.skaele.it/Home/Search)

Whenever I type data to any column's search-feild in my Jqgrid, I'm able to receive json get request. For example, when I type "Kei" in to the search textbox of the Name colunm in the JqGrid table, I receive a GET application/json request that looks something like this:

[Not a real link used for example]

```
http://local/Home/CallGrid?_search=true&nd=1388596935527&rows=10&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc&filters=%7B%22groupOp%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22Name%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22bw%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22Kei%22%7D%5D%7D
```

The problem that I'm having is that the current data on my json table is not being filtered by the GET application/json request. I'm using Firefox to due my debugging. For example if i type 'p' on the email column the content of the query-parameter and json content looks like what's below but nothing ever get filtered:

**Query Parameter**

```
Parameter          Value

_search                true

nd           1388537724720

rows      10

page      1

sidx       

sord       asc

filters    {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"EmailAddress","op":"bw","data":"p"}]}
```

**Content**

```
Type: application/json

{"total":2,"page":1,"records":14,"filters":"{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":
[{\"field\":\"CallTransTypeDesc\",\"op\":\"bw\",\"data\":\"p\"}]}","SortColumn":"",
"SortOrder":"asc","rows":[{"CallTransTypeDesc":"Customer Service",
"CallTransCodeDesc":"ANSWER QUESTION/RESENT KIT",
"CallTransSiteLocation":"Houston, TX","AgentIdentifier":"ROKUNEYE"},
{"CallTransTypeDesc":"Customer Service","CallTransCodeDesc":
"CROSS SELL NOT OFFERED CSV","CallTransSiteLocation":"Houston, TX",
"AgentIdentifier":"ROKUNEYE"},
{"CallTransTypeDesc":"Customer Service","CallTransCodeDesc":
"TRV/FRM/COMPANION TICKET","CallTransSiteLocation":"Westerville, OH",
"AgentIdentifier":"JAALLEN"},
{"CallTransTypeDesc":"Customer Service","CallTransCodeDesc":
"TRV/RBT/$40 GAS COUPON","CallTransSiteLocation":"Westerville, OH",
"AgentIdentifier":"JAALLEN"},
{"CallTransTypeDesc":"Customer Service","CallTransCodeDesc":
"CROSS SELL NOT ACCEPTED CSV","CallTransSiteLocation":"Westerville, OH",
"AgentIdentifier":"JAALLEN"},
{"CallTransTypeDesc":"Customer Service","CallTransCodeDesc":
"30 DAYS TERM EXTENSION","CallTransSiteLocation":"Westerville, OH",
"AgentIdentifier":"JAALLEN"},
{"CallTransTypeDesc":"Save","CallTransCodeDesc":"BENEFIT ONLY SAVE",
"CallTransSiteLocation":"Westerville, OH","AgentIdentifier":"JAALLEN"},
{"CallTransTypeDesc":"Save","CallTransCodeDesc":"BENEFIT ONLY SAVE",
"CallTransSiteLocation":"Westerville, OH","AgentIdentifier":"JAALLEN"},
{"CallTransTypeDesc":"Fulfillment","CallTransCodeDesc":null,
"CallTransSiteLocation":
"Westerville, OH","AgentIdentifier":"JAALLEN"},
{"CallTransTypeDesc":"Fulfillment","CallTransCodeDesc":null,
"CallTransSiteLocation":
"Westerville, OH","AgentIdentifier":"JAALLEN"}]}
```

My only conclusion is that I have to add `QueryStringParameter` of C# Class into my controller so that I can get the json filtered parameter from my url into part of the controller that deals with passing the json data. But I'm not to sure on how I would do this. Any suggestion and references would be greatly appreciated.

I believe the main area to fix this json search/filter issue will  be in the controller here's what the controller looks like:

```
public JsonResult CallGrid(GridSettings settings, string sord, string sidx, bool _search, NamedQueryCallInfo filter, string filters)

        {



        // Controller for Grid  code to work on view  TranHistViewGrid.cshtml

       //string rice = settings.SortColumn;

        //  string wice =  settings.SortOrder





        //Gets the Referer Header string url string

        Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;



        // repersents data for the postService value found above in the Referer url

        string postService = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(MyUrl.Query).Get("postService");



        // repersents data for the postMemberId value found above in the Referer url

        string postMemberId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(MyUrl.Query).Get("postMemberId");



        // repersents data for the postJoinDate value found above in the Referer url

        string postJoinDate1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(MyUrl.Query).Get("postJoinDate");

        DateTime postJoinDate = Convert.ToDateTime(postJoinDate1);





        //Nhibernate code Connection to obtain query.



        NhbHelper.NHibernateHelperBizin nbh;

        nbh = new NhbHelper.NHibernateHelperBizin();

        ISession nhbSession = NHibernateHelperBizin.GetCurrentSession();

        ITransaction nhbTransaction = nhbSession.BeginTransaction();

        //IQueryable<NamedQueryCallInfo> customers = null;

       // NamedQueryCallInfo customerRepository = new  NamedQueryCallInfo();

        IQuery nhbQuery = nhbSession.GetNamedQuery("NamedQueryCallInfo");



        nhbQuery.SetParameter("queryparamContractId", postMemberId);

        nhbQuery.SetParameter("queryparamService", postService);

        nhbQuery.SetParameter("queryparamJoinDate", postJoinDate);



        //queryList instantiate query value to pass vaules in the query code mapped to database

        IList<NamedQueryCallInfo> queryList1 = nhbQuery.SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers

.AliasToBean(typeof(NamedQueryCallInfo))).List<NamedQueryCallInfo>();



        /*

                    //------------------

         * var context = new HaackOverflowDataContext();

                    var context = new HaackOverflowEntities();

                    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                    Filters f = (!_search || string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters)) ? null : serializer.Deserialize<Filters>(filters);

                    ObjectQuery<NamedQueryCallInfo> filteredQuery =

                        (f == null ? context.Questions : f.FilterObjectSet(context.Questions));

                    filteredQuery.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;

                    //------------------------------

        */

      //  NamedQueryCallInfo filter = new NamedQueryCallInfo();

       // var orderedCustomers = OrderCustomers(customers, settings.SortColumn, settings.SortOrder);



        if (settings.IsSearch)

        {







            // filter.CallTransDate = settings.Where.rules.Any(r => r.field == "CallTransDate") ?

            //    DateTime.ParseExact(settings.Where.rules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.field == "CallTransDate").data,

            //               "M/d/yyyy", null) : DateTime.MinValue;



            filter.Service = settings.Where.rules.Any(r => r.field == "CallTransTypeDesc") ?

                settings.Where.rules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.field == "CallTransTypeDesc").data : string.Empty;

            filter.Service = settings.Where.rules.Any(r => r.field == "CallTransCodeDesc") ?

                settings.Where.rules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.field == "CallTransCodeDesc").data : string.Empty;

            filter.Service = settings.Where.rules.Any(r => r.field == "CallTransSiteLocation") ?

                settings.Where.rules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.field == "CallTransSiteLocation").data : string.Empty;

            filter.Service = settings.Where.rules.Any(r => r.field == "AgentIdentifier") ?

                settings.Where.rules.FirstOrDefault(r => r.field == "AgentIdentifier").data : string.Empty;

        }

            //string x = settings.SortOrder;

            //string  y = settings.SortColumn;





        // NamedQueryCallInfo customerRepository = new  NamedQueryCallInfo();





        //--IList<NamedQueryCallInfo> customerRepository = null;

          //  var customers = customerRepository.ToArray(filter, settings.SortColumn, settings.SortOrder, settings.PageIndex );







        //ReplicationMode ytr = new ReplicationMode();

      //  CallGrid(GridSettings r, sord, sidx);

        int count = queryList1.Count();  //--- number of total items from query

        int page = settings.PageIndex;

        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)count / settings.PageSize);



        // CallGrid(); try to take out the sord and sidx above

        var questions = queryList1;

        /*

        customers = customerRepository.CallGrid(filter,

                                         settings.SortColumn,

                                         settings.SortOrder,

                                         settings.PageSize,

                                         settings.PageIndex,

                                         out totalPages);

       */





        // instantiation that gives varable data test the ability to act like linq and convert query data to Json data.

        var test = questions.AsQueryable<NamedQueryCallInfo>().Select(c => c);

        IEnumerable<NamedQueryCallInfo> sortedRecords = test.ToList();



        //sortedRecords = orderedCustomers.sortedRecords;



        if (sord == "desc")

            //string w = settings.SortOrder;



            sortedRecords = sortedRecords.Reverse();

        sortedRecords = sortedRecords.Skip((settings.PageIndex - 1) * settings.PageSize).Take(settings.PageSize).ToArray();





        //----------------------

        var result = new

        {

            total = totalPages, //--- number of pages

            page,               //--- current page

            records = count,    //--- total items

            //filters,







            rows = (from p in sortedRecords

                    select new

                    {

                      //  CallTransDate = p.CallTransDate.ToShortDateString(),

                        CallTransTypeDesc = p.CallTransTypeDesc,

                        CallTransCodeDesc = p.CallTransCodeDesc,

                        CallTransSiteLocation = p.CallTransSiteLocation,

                        AgentIdentifier = p.AgentIdentifier,



                    }).ToArray()




        };







        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

---

Here's what my view looks like:

```
@(Html.Grid("search")

.SetCaption("Jq-Grid Call View")

//.SetLoadUi(MvcJqGrid.Enums.LoadUi.Enable)

.SetRequestType(RequestType.Get)

.SetViewRecords(true)

 //  .AddColumn(new Column("CallTransDate")

 //   .SetLabel("Call Date").SetSearch(true).SetSearchType(MvcJqGrid.Enums.Searchtype.Datepicker).SetSearchDateFormat("M/d/yyyy").SetSearchOption(MvcJqGrid.Enums.SearchOptions.Equal))

.AddColumn(new Column("CallTransTypeDesc").SetLabel("Call Type Desc").SetSearch(true).SetSearchOption(SearchOptions.BeginsWith))

.AddColumn(new Column("CallTransCodeDesc").SetLabel("Call Code Desc").SetSearch(true).SetSearchOption(SearchOptions.BeginsWith).SetSortable(true))

.AddColumn(new Column("CallTransSiteLocation").SetLabel("Call Site Location").SetSearch(true).SetSearchOption(SearchOptions.BeginsWith))

.AddColumn(new Column("AgentIdentifier").SetLabel("Agent Identifier").SetSearch(true).SetSearchOption(SearchOptions.BeginsWith))

.SetUrl(Url.Action("CallGrid", "Kore"))

// .SetUrl("~/Home/TranHistViewGrid")

.SetAutoEncode(true)

.SetDataType(DataType.Json)

.SetJsonReader(jsonReader)

.SetLoadUi(LoadUi.Block)

.SetAutoWidth(true)

.SetSortOnHeaderClick(true)

.SetRowList(new[]{10,15,20,50})

//.SetSearchClearButton(true)

.SetRowNum(10)

.SetToolbar(true)

.SetSearchToolbar(true).SetSearchOnEnter(false)

  .SetShowAllSortIcons(true)

 .SetShrinkToFit(true)

 .SetIgnoreCase(true)

 .SetPager("pager")

 .OnLoadBeforeSend("addGridSearchOption")

 .SetGridView(true)

 //.OnSerializeGridData("function (data) {return JSON.stringify(data);}")





 )
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    /*

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {



        $("#search").setGriddParam({ datatype: 'json', page: 10 }).trigger('reloadGrid');

    }

    ); */





    function addGridSearchOption(grid, fieldName, fieldValue) {

        if (grid[0].p.search == false) {

           f = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [] };

            f.rules.push({ field: fieldName, op: "bw", data: fieldValue });

            grid[0].p.search = true;

            $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: JSON.stringify(f) });

        }

        else {

            tFilters = eval('(' + grid[0].p.postData.filters + ')');

            var bAddRule = true;

            var i = 0;

            for (var tRule in tFilters.rules) {

                if (tFilters.rules[i].field == fieldName) {

                    tFilters.rules[i].data = fieldValue;

                    bAddRule = false;

                }

                i++;

            }

            if (bAddRule) {

                tFilters.rules.push({ field: fieldName, op: "bw", data: fieldValue });

            } grid[0].p.postData.filters = JSON.stringify(tFilters);



        }

    }







/*

    function processrequest(postdata) {



        $.ajax({



            complete: function (jsondata, stat) {

                if (stat == "success") {

                    var thegrid = jQuery("#list2")[0];

                    var jsonObject = (eval("(" + jsondata.responseText + ")"));

                    thegrid.addJSONData(jsonObject.d);

                    $(".loading").hide();

                } else {

                    $(".loading").hide();

                    alert("Error with AJAX callback");

                }

                $("#search").setGridParam({ datatype: 'local' });

            }

        });

    }

    */

    //jQuery("#search").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });



</script>
```

Comment: The json content contains 'p' in the data field when you type 'p' in emailaddress. So this is good. This means the problem is on the serverside. Have you examined gridsettings object with debugger? It should also contain a data field, and it should be filled with 'p'. If so, the problem is probably in your queries. Can you confirm the searchterm 'p' reaches the controller through the GridSettings object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to use this line of command in your server side codes.

```
jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });
```